# implementing ckeditor in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to implement ckeditor in laravel 5. I have already installed IvoryCKEditorBundle. but for implementation the docs says to register a new form field type called ckeditor that extends the textarea.

How should I do that?

Comment: That is a symfony bundle.  I don't think it will work for Laravel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't need a bundle to use CKEditor - you can download the whole package of js files from the [ckeditor website](http://ckeditor.com/download).   Once you have it, place the folder containing all the downloaded files inside of your js folder

In your view you can now reference the ckeditor.js file:

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}
```

Next include a short ckeditor script, which can include custom configuration (edit config in the js/plugins/ckeditor folder):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         CKEDITOR.replace( 'messageArea',
         {
          customConfig : 'config.js',
          toolbar : 'simple'
          })
</script>
```

add .ckeditor as a class in your textarea:

```
<textarea id="messageArea" name="messageArea" rows="7" class="form-control ckeditor" placeholder="Write your message.."></textarea>
```

if you are posting your content using ajax, use something like this to get the textarea value:

```
var message = CKEDITOR.instances.messageArea.getData();
```

Comment: can you help me, how to give value of this textarea using jquery or js ? thanks!

Comment: Even you can use CDN as well, great guide here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this you can do it by 1 minute.

```
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get resources from //cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js
Download from here and put /public/ckeditor/

```
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary-ckeditor' );
</script>
```

**or** If you want to use CDN then above code would be as follow:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary-ckeditor' );
</script>
```